# How to groupBy by created column?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->select('u.id as user_id', 'u.username as username', 'u.companyName', 'month(o.checkedAt) as month', 'identity(l.productCategory) as product_category',
                'a.street', 'a.zip', 'a.apartmentNo', 'a.city', 'a.streetNo')
            ->join(User::class, 'u', Join::WITH, 'o.user = u')
            ->join(UserAddress::class, 'a', Join::WITH, 'u.id = a.user')
            ->join(OrderLens::class, 'l', Join::WITH, 'l.order = o.id')
            ->groupBy('o.user')
            ->addGroupBy('month');
[...]
```

> I receive Notice: Undefined index: month
> How can I group my records by those 2 variables?
> Without ->groupBy('month') it works 100% correctly

Comment: I'd like to groupBy by this value:
'month(o.checkedAt) as month'

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I did not see you already added `month(o.checkedAt) as month`, you can remove what I said previously and just edit your addGroupBy with another alias.

Change your alias used by your `month(o.checkedAt)`

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->select('u.id as user_id', 'u.username as username',
               'u.companyName', 'month(o.checkedAt) as cMonth', 
               'identity(l.productCategory) as product_category',
               'a.street', 'a.zip', 'a.apartmentNo', 'a.city', 'a.streetNo')
            ->join(User::class, 'u', Join::WITH, 'o.user = u')
            ->join(UserAddress::class, 'a', Join::WITH, 'u.id = a.user')
            ->join(OrderLens::class, 'l', Join::WITH, 'l.order = o.id')
            ->groupBy('o.user')
            ->addGroupBy('cMonth');
```

Comment: Got
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 434: Error: Expected end of string, got ‘(’

Query:
`SELECT u.id as user_id, u.username as username, u.companyName, month(o.checkedAt) as month, identity(l.productCategory) as product_category, a.street, a.zip, a.apartmentNo, a.city, a.streetNo, month(o.checkedAt) FROM App\Order\Entity\Order o INNER JOIN App\User\Entity\User u WITH o.user = u INNER JOIN App\User\Entity\UserAddress a WITH u.id = a.user INNER JOIN App\Order\Entity\OrderLens l WITH l.order = o.id GROUP BY o.user, month(o.checkedAt)`